Can I have a dynamic filter based on user input?
I have a table that is generated from a power BI dataset and returns a table as follows:



Organization[OpCo]
Clients[Client Code]




Alabama
ABCINC


Alabama
FASTTRA



the below "command text" is a copy and past from the connection properties dialog box.    I did not write it.    You'll see the line that reads:
TREATAS({"Alabama"}, 'Organization'[OpCo])
I would like "Alabama" to be a variable based on either:

user selection on a separate tab called "Dashboard" in Cell A1
OR preferable a
function called "Choose_OpCo()"

The goal is that when the user changes the OpCo in cell A1 on the Dashboard tab, this table will update with the new information for the OpCo that was selected.
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
        TREATAS({"Alabama"}, 'Organization'[OpCo])

    VAR __DS0Core = 
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            KEEPFILTERS(
                FILTER(
                    KEEPFILTERS(
                        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                            'Organization'[OpCo],
                            'Clients'[Client Code],
                            __DS0FilterTable,
                            "CountRowsFactPolicy", COUNTROWS('FactPolicy')
                        )
                    ),
                    OR(
                        NOT(ISBLANK('Organization'[OpCo])),
                        NOT(ISBLANK('Clients'[Client Code]))
                    )
                )
            ),
            "'Organization'[OpCo]", 'Organization'[OpCo],
            "'Clients'[Client Code]", 'Clients'[Client Code]
        )

    VAR __DS0BodyLimited = 
        TOPN(500000, __DS0Core, 'Organization'[OpCo], 1, 'Clients'[Client Code], 1)

EVALUATE
    __DS0BodyLimited

ORDER BY
    'Organization'[OpCo], 'Clients'[Client Code]

